# how to config I2S master clock in STM32F730?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, i2s

I want to change MCLK f<sub>s</sub> rates for 44100 sample rate audio on STM32F703.

Right now my clock in STM32 is 207.36MHz

I2S PLL values: `N=147, R=2, Q=2 and PLLI2SDivQ=10`

I2S clock is supplied with PLLI2SR which clock is 112.896.

I have changed PLLI2SDivQ values but it doesn't affect the I2S MCLK clock I have observed it on Oscilloscope and its 112.896MHz even when PLLI2SDivQ is 10 or 5

Comment: STM32 is a broad series of MCUs with very different PLL and clock-tree implementations across different devices.  You will need to be more specific about the part you are using.

Comment: What oscillator are you using, and if HSE what is the input frequency? The STM32CubeMX tool (or Cube IDE) includes a clock tree calculator.  Useful, even if you are not using the code it can generate for you.  For some older parts, ST  provided an Excel spreadsheet clock calculator ( which to be honest is easier to use than Cube).

Comment: I have looked up in the ref manual of the Stm32f730 I found out that Masterclock rate to sample rate is a fixed value of 256 and it can not be changed in i2s

Comment: "_I found out that Masterclock rate to sample rate is a fixed value of 256 and it can not be changed in i2s_"  That only true if you set MCKOE=1, which bypasses the fixed /4 and /2 bit clock divider.  If you do not need the I2S master clock output, set that to zero. You should scope the I2S bit-clock to verify the bit rate, which is not the same as sample rate of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The I2S clock determines the *bit rate*, not the *sample_rate* for for 44.1ksps 16 bit stereo, you would need a bit rate of 1.4112x10<sup>6</sup>bps

The clock rate generator is as follows:
[image]

<sup>Ref: STM32F72xx/3xx RM0431</sup>

With your stated configuration I<sup>2</sup>SxCLK is 11.2896MHz

And the sample rate is calculated per:
[image]

<sup>Ref: STM32F72xx/3xx RM0431</sup>

So for 44.1ksps you need the denominator in the appropriate formula above to be 11.2896MHz / 44.1ksps = 256

So for I2S mode 16-bit x 2, MCKOE=0:

`32 x ((2 × I2SDIV) + ODD) = 256` is achieved when I2SDIV = 4 and ODD=0.